# Showing that a preference relation admits a utility function representation

Tags: utility, preferences

**Setting:** We have two choices of goods $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ from the set of choices $[-1,1]^2$. Moreover, we have the following preference relation $$(x_1,y_1)\mathcal{R}(x_2,y_2)\iff |x_1|\geq|x_2|\>\>\text{or}\>\> |y_1|\geq|y_2|$$

**Question:** We have to check if there exists a utility function reprensation of this preference relation.

**My attempt:** So from what I have learned, we know that a preference relation admits a utility function representation *if* it is rational (reflexive, complete, transitive) and continuous. I have found that this preference relation is not transitive, but this does not mean that there does not exist a utility function representation, because the aforementioned statement is not an *if and only if* statement.

Moreover, I thought we could try to derive a contradiction from the fact that if there exists a utility function $u$ representation of the preference relation, then we have $$(x_1,y_1)\mathcal{R}(x_2,y_2)\iff u(x_1,y_1)\geq u(x_2,y_2)$$
I tried to use the fact that the relation is not transitive to derive a contradiction by using the statement above, but was unsuccessful.

Sadly, these are the two main theorems/propositions that I've learned to solve these problems.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use the violation of transitivity and proceed by contradiction.

Suppose you have  that $(x_1,y_1)R(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_2,y_2)R(x_3,y_3)$ and a utility function, $u:[-1,1]^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, exists, then $u(x_1,y_1)\geq u(x_2,y_2)$ (these are two reals) and $u(x_2,y_2)\geq u(x_3,y_3)$. (another two reals). Since the reals are transitive, we conclude  $u(x_1,y_1)\geq u(x_3,y_3)$ which in turn implies that $(x_1,y_1)R(x_3,y_3)$. However this is a contradiction (if you choose carefully your three bunddles).

Answer (score 2):

Transitivity and completeness are actually *necessary* for the existence of a utility representation. Whenever you prove that preferences fail to be complete or transitive you can conclude that they do *not* admit a utility function. 
For finite choice sets $X$, transitivity and completeness are necessary and sufficient, see Theorem 5 [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1cdc/4f88148c2573769f2763897f831963015524.pdf).

Contrary to what you suggest, continuity is not itself necessary, but it is almost necessary. What you need is a condition called separability. Say that $\succcurlyeq$ is separable if there exists a *countable* set $Z \subseteq X$ such that for every $x,y\in X$ there exists some $z\in Z$ such that $x\succcurlyeq z \succcurlyeq y$.

**Theorem** A preference relation $\succcurlyeq$ on $X$ admits a utility representation if and only if it is complete, transitive, and separable.

This is actually a very old result by Cantor that precedes the well-known result by Debreu—which assumes continuity. Cantor's result was brought into Economics by Kreps. You can find a proof [here, Theorem 9](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1cdc/4f88148c2573769f2763897f831963015524.pdf).

Comment: "Whenever you prove that preferences fail to be *continuous* or transitive..." Did you mean "**complete** or transitive"?

Comment: Let me suggest the edit above.